# Name for collection of command objects

Tags: java, oop, naming-conventions

I am developing a command handler where each command can have sub-commands indefinitely. All commands are managed at the root level by a "CommandManager" which takes user input parses options then finds the right command and passes the input to it. As both the CommandManager and the Command both have a similar way of getting and storing specified commands and as both classes are very cluttered I would like to factor out the logic that finds and stores commands into a common superclass, however, I can't think of a descriptive name to call it.

The reason for me to try and make the CommandMagager and the Command both extend another class is that the command manager acts like a command at the root level. Commands don't actually contain any logic to process commands, they just provide a way to register and retrieve commands with a certain name.

Are there any general conventions that may help me find a name or is this the wrong way to be looking at the problem?

Comment: One of your classes should be a CommandFactory because it is analyzing the parameters received to determine what is the correct command to use.

Comment: @JorgeGarita I always thought of factories as objects that create objects, in my case the manager only finds the right instance of an object.

Comment: It sounds to me like this might be a strategy pattern. 

Your Commands hold encapsulated segments of logic that can be interchanged. The parent class that you talk about will validate what data has been received and decide what segment of logic to apply from it, avoiding code duplication.

Comment: If the task of a `CommandManager` is to parse user inputs and produce executable commands, I don't see how it may have something in common with a `Command`. It would beneficial if you could describe better the responsibilities of both classes.

Comment: Try to be more specific. Provide an example of some responsibility shared by both classes that would be representative of the kind of code they have in common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there are a few rules about that, nothing written in stone, just kind of practices which became accepted best practices by experience and imitation.

## Overview

- Make the responsibility clear.
- Use Camel Case.
- Name objects, not classes.
- Use nouns.
- Avoid words like `Info`, `Processor` or `Manager`.
- Use singular if there are objects.
- Use plural for utility classes.
- Prefix abstract base class with `Abstract`.
- Suffix hidden implementation class with `Impl`.
- Do not prefix `interface` names with `I`.
- Use design pattern names correctly.
- Prefix names with their specialization.
- Use data structure names correctly

## Details

### Make the Responsibility Clear

It's important that the name reflects the responsibility nicely. The name shall communicate its intent.

### Name Objects, not Classes

Use a name which looks good when using a single object. Name the object, not the class.

### Use Camel Case

UseCamelCaseForNamesOfTypesInJava.

### Use nouns

Use nouns for objects. If the object represents an action, turn the verb into a noun. If the object represents an attribute, turn the adjective into a noun. For example, if the action is `compile()`, use `Compiler` if it is an active action, or `Compilable` if it is a passive ability. If the action is `run()`, use `Runner` if it is an active action, `Runnable` if it is a passive ability.

### Avoid words like `Info`, `Processor` or `Manager`

In most of the cases, they're just synonyms for "I don't know what to call this" (Robert C. Martin). This itself is a symptom of "I don't know what this thing is doing" or "This thing is doing more than one thing". Which is why we often rightfully feel the urge to refactor when we see such names.

### Use singular if there are objects

Class names usually are singular, especially if you can obtain multiple objects of a single class. We like to reserve the plural for variable names of collections of such objects.

#### Good Example

```
JButton button;
List<JButton> buttons;
```

#### Bad Example

`Properties` is a bad class name because it is plural although there are objects. We like to call a `List<JButton>` `jButtons`. So, how do you call a `List<Properties>` - `propertiess`? `propertieses`? `propertiessies`???

### Use plural for utility classes

A class is a utility class if it contains only static methods which exist for the sole purpose to provide utility methods for another type.

#### Good Examples

`Collections`, `Spilterators`, `Arrays`, `Executors`, `FileSystems`, `Files`, `Paths`.

### Prefix abstract base class with `Abstract`

An abstract base implementation for an interface `Foo` is usually called `AbstractFoo`.

Examples: `AbstractAction`, `AbstractList`, `AbstractMap`, `AbstractQueue` and so forth.

Make sure that this name is a name the user would hardly ever see, `AbstractSomething` is a nice name for the implementor / extensor, not for the user. And only choose this name in the absence of a better name.

### Suffix hidden implementation class with `Impl`

A class which provides the default implementation for an interface or abstract class `Foo` is sometimes just called `FooImpl`.

Make sure the user never sees this name. Never ever. It's only good for the implementor, nobody else. A name like `XyzImpl` must not be visible to the user. And only choose this name in the absence of a better name.

### Do not prefix `interface` names with `I`

The purpose of a type in an OO language usually is to encapsulate and hide things. Whether a type is a `class`, an `interface`, an `enum` or an `@interface` annotation is a detail of that type. There are only two situations where you need to know these details about a type: When you want to extend the type, and when you want to create an object of that type. These use cases are the minority of the use cases of types. By prefixing interface names with `I`, you violate this principle by loudly declaring an implementation detail that in fact should be hidden.

Putting an `I` in front of the names of `interface`s is like using Hungarian notation. Hungarian notation only makes sense when you're working in an environment where keeping track of these physical aspects of your types is essential. (And for that matter it even is not necessary in C these days!)

Besides, you don't want to look like an idiot when

- You decide to change a class in an interface or vice versa and do not rename the type, you end up with an interface without `I`-prefix or a class with `I`-prefix.
- You decide to change a class in an interface or vice versa and rename the type, you end up annoying your users.
- Oracle removes the differences between `class` and `interface` in a future version of Java (not so unlikely, look at how interfaces have static and default methods now).
- You port your API to another language which doesn't distinguish between `class` and `interface` and now have classes with `I` prefix, or classes which have different names.

### Use Design Pattern Names Correctly

If you use a design pattern, you may use its name if it seems appropriate. But if you do not use a design pattern, avoid names of design patterns.

It's optional to use a design pattern name when using a design pattern - use it if it helps or is common practice to use the name of the design pattern, like the `Factory`-suffix for abstract factories.

But it's almost mandatory to avoid a design pattern name when you're actually not using it. It might be confusing if you name something `Command` but it doesn't implement the *Command pattern*, if you name something `Strategy` but it doesn't implement the *Strategy pattern*, if you name something `Factory` but it doesn't implement the *Factory pattern*.

It's not always confusing, some judgement might be required. For example, you might have a framework for writing command line programs with an interface and an abstract base class for these command line programs. You might want to call them `Command` and `AbstractCommand` despite the fact that this is not really the *Command design pattern*, at least not from the perspective of the language itself.

#### Examples where the name is used

- `KeyFactory` *Factory* design pattern
- `DocumentBuilder` *Builder* design pattern
- `Action` *Command* design pattern (aka *Action*, *Transaction*)

#### Examples where the name is not used

- `Runnable`, `Callable` - *Command* design pattern but different, more specialized names.
- `Collections.synchronizedList()` - *Factory Method* for a *Decorator*

### Prefix Names with their Specialization

It is common for class names to grow as we advance downwards in the inheritance tree by prefixing the name of a base class with information about the specialization.

#### Examples

- `List`: `AbstractList`, `ArrayList`, `AbstractSequentialList`, `LinkedList`
- `Set`: `AbstractSet`, `HashSet`, `LinkedHashSet`

### Use data structure names correctly

If you implement data structures, use the appropriate names.

The concept of having key/value pairs regardless of how they are maintained is called *dictionary*, so an interface describing that should be named *Dictionary*. (The reason that Java named it *Map* instead was that the original collections in Java 1.0 were purely designed and already used an abstract class `Dictionary`, so the `interface` needed a new name.)

## Your Case

In your case, I could imagine the following design:

- `interface Command { void execute(); }` for everything that can be executed.
- `interface CommandQueue { void submit(Command); }` for something to which commands can be submitted.
- `interface CommandRunner extends CommandQueue { void start(); void stop(); }`

I could update this section in case you give a little bit more details. For something which queues and processes commands you might also want to think about parallelization and have a look at `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: I have tried to think of a different name for my `CommandManager` but cannot think of anything other than `CommandProcessor` which is almost as bad. The class seems to only have a single responsibility and is basically just a `HashMap` with a method to find a root level command and find the correct sub-command (which can be many layers deep). Maybe `CommandDispatcher` could be a good name? but it doesn't seem to show that it also stores commands.

Comment: Did you already look at `java.util.concurrent`? You could use two different names for what is being scheduled for execution and what executes them, just like `java.util.concurrent` does. `CommandDispatcher` sounds nice, and I'd say that it's implicit that a `Dispatcher` might have a queue. If the `CommandDispatcher` is or could be running multiple threads, you could also think of `CommandScheduler`.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you describe your model it looks like you are dealing with something very close to a composition pattern (CM is the root command, while C represents individual commands.)
If this is the case, then the names you are trying to find are:

```
Command
    CompositeCommand
    SimpleCommand
```

In other words, what you've called `CommandManager` would play the role of `CompositeCommand`, your current `Command` class would be `SimpleCommand` and, finally, the (abstract) superclass your are looking for would be `Command` in the terminology I'm proposing. Both the root as well as any other nested commands would be instances of `CompositeCommand`. Of course, if the root has some special behavior you could also model this as:

```
Command
    CompositeCommand
        RootCommand
    SimpleCommand
```

This way, `RootCommand` would take the place of your `CommandManager`, it would be composite in itself and any other command with subcommands will be of class `CompositeCommand`, while "leaves" would be of class `SimpleCommand`.

I know, some people will dislike concrete classes with subclasses. If that is your case you should do something like this:

```
Command
    CompositeCommand
        Subcommand
        RootCommand
    SimpleCommand
```

Now `Command` and `CompositeCommand` are abstract and all three concrete classes are subclass free.

You might still be wondering why I'm using so many names and not `CommandManager`. It is because, in my opinition, there is no such thing as a command *manager*.

Finally, you might need another object (from a different hierarchy), say `CommandParser`, that would provide parsing services in a more abstract way. The `Command` hierarchy would use the services of the parser and add semantics to otherwise abstract tokens. It is very likely that this separation will bring more simplicity to the `Command` code. At the same time it would decouple the syntax of your command language from the internal representation, which would add more flexibility to your design because you could offer, say, two different syntaxes without having to modify the `Command` hierarchy.